# Laravel Eloquent whereIn with where inside relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an relationship structure like this:

Place `hasMany` Service
`Service` `belongsTo` `ServiceType`

I'm trying to filter it by `ServiceType`, but i always get a error trying various types saying that the table or view doesn't exist.

```
$place = Place::with('services.serviceTypes')->whereIn('id', $ids)
->where('services.serviceTypes.id', $id)->get();
```

or

```
$place = Place::with('services.serviceTypes')->whereIn('id', $ids)
->where('services.service_types.id', $id)->get();
```

returns the same exception.

Models:

Place:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Place extends Model {  

    public function services(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Service');
    }

}
```

Service:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Service extends Model {

    public function serviceType(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ServiceType');
    }


}
```

ServiceType:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ServiceType extends Model {

    public function services() {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Service');
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code that contains your relations definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To query relationships, you need to use the specific functions available for that. You're looking for the `whereHas()` method.

```
$place = Place::with('services.serviceTypes')
    ->whereIn('id', $ids)
    ->whereHas('services.serviceTypes', function ($query) use ($id) {
        return $query->where('id', $id);
    })
    ->get();
```

You can read more about [querying relationships here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).